# Using JAXB to create spring bean and necessary properties

Tags: java, jaxb

I am having trouble customizing my JAXB Marshaller. I have my marshaller code:

```
public void marshaller(AddressMap addMap, File file) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressMap.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(addMap, System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ObjectMap>
 <Prop> Indiana</Prop>
 <Prop1>39.0</Prop1>
 <Prop2>-85.0</Prop2>
 <Prop3> United States</Prop3>
 <Prop4> Hueseman Rd</Prop4>
 <Prop5> 8540-8704</Prop5>
 <Prop6> 47001</Prop6>
</ObjectMap>
```

Instead, I need it to look like this:

```
<bean class="classname">
    <property name="PropName" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName1" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName2" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName3" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName4" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName5" value="object value" />
    <property name="PropName6" value="object value" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Add the definition of your `AddressMap` class.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Add namespaces? Or annotations?

Comment: JAXB binds annotated POJO's to XML. In this case the POJO is your `AddressMap` class. We need to see how you've defined it in order to be able to help you. So, please include relevant portion of the code from it, in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's `@XmlDesciminatorNode` and `@XmlPath` extensions to map this use case.  Below is an example based on what I assume your object model looks like.

**ObjectMap**

The `@XmlDescriminatorNode` annotation allows you to specify that you want a specific XML attribute to serve as the inheritance indicator.

```
package forum13884782;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlDiscriminatorNode;

@XmlRootElement(name="bean")
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@class")
public class ObjectMap {

}
```

**AddressMap**

The `@XmlDescriminatorValue` annotation is used to specify the value on the descriminator node that relates to the instance class.  In this class we also use the `@XmlPath` annotation to indicate which `property` element we wish to map to based on the value of its `name` attribute.

```
package forum13884782;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="bean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("AddressMap")
public class AddressMap extends ObjectMap {

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName']/@value")
    String prop;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName1']/@value")
    String prop1;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName2']/@value")
    String prop2;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName3']/@value")
    String prop3;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName4']/@value")
    String prop4;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName5']/@value")
    String prop5;

    @XmlPath("property[@name='PropName6']/@value")
    String prop6;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

The following demo code will convert the XML message to an instance of `AddressMap` and then back to XML.

```
package forum13884782;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressMap.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum13884782/input.xml");
        AddressMap addressMap = (AddressMap) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(addressMap, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<bean class="AddressMap">
    <property name="PropName" value="Indiana" />
    <property name="PropName1" value="39.0" />
    <property name="PropName2" value="-85.0" />
    <property name="PropName3" value="United States" />
    <property name="PropName4" value="Hueseman Rd" />
    <property name="PropName5" value="8540-8704" />
    <property name="PropName6" value="47001" />
</bean>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html